# How to structure an app which uses a mobile phone to transmit audio via UDP

Tags: node.js, react-native, udp

I need some help structuring an App that allows for a speaker who can send audio via his/her phone mic and then for users to listen to this audio stream. I don't want to upload anything to the cloud as there may be bad internet reception.
What technologies to use? How do they talk to together?

Currently I have:

1. Have a mobile dongle that everyone connects to
2. host a server on this dongle?
3. Send an live audio stream to this server via UDP
4. Users listen to this server
   Ideally it would be great if I could build this in React Native, which I think is possible. I am not sure how to host a server on a dongle though or even if this the best method?